# What does 'symbol-keyed' mean in `JSON.stringify`

Tags: javascript, stringify, sequelize.js

There is a Object generated by Node.js, it looks like this when I use `console.log`:

```
{ dataValues: { a: 1, b: 2 }, fn1: function(){}, fn2: function(){} }
```

when I use `JSON.stringify`, it return this string:

```
{"a":1,"b":1}
```

I checked the mozilla developer center and found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> All **symbol-keyed** properties will be completely ignored, even when using the replacer function.

I think the 'dataValues' must be the 'symbol-keyed' property, but what does 'symbol-keyed' mean?

btw, I use the [sequelizejs](http://sequelizejs.com/) ORM lib to generate this object.

Comment: `"{ 'a': 1, 'b': 1}"` is invalid JSON. I can't see how `JSON.stringify` could have produced that. How did you use it?

Comment: sorry, the string is wrong, I have modified it to right format.

Comment: @TomWan: If you use `JSON.stringify` on what you've quoted, you will not get `{"a":1,"b":1}`, you'll get `{"dataValues":{"a":1,"b":2}}`; proof: http://jsbin.com/ralova/1

Comment: I wrote JavaScript for 3 years, I know it is impossible in browser, It happend in NodeJS, you can write some code with NodeJS and SequelizeJS and get some data from MySQL and see how it returns by Promise.

Answer (score 4):

I found the reason finally in the same [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value is a function, then the toJSON method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the toJSON method when called will be serialized.

It runs on browser normally.
    Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomwan/s5epz872/2) to run it like I asked.

Code:

```
function test(data) {
    for(var key in data){
        this[key] = data[key];
    }
}

test.prototype.toJSON = function(){
    return this.dataValues;
}

var a = new test({dataValues: {a:1, b:2}});

console.log(a);//the instance
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));//{"a":1,"b":1}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nah, the relevant part to your issue is this blurb:

> If undefined, a **function**, or a symbol is encountered during conversion
>   it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to
>   null (when it is found in an array).

So in other words, if your JSON object contains functions, they are omitted during the JSON.stringify process.

"symbol-keyed" refers to a new primitive type introduced in ecmascript6. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof for more info.

This is an example of a "symbol-keyed" property:

```
{[Symbol("foo")]: "foo"}
```

Reference for JavaScript Symbol: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Comment: This doesn't explain why `dataValues` is missing from the result.

Comment: I write the Symbol in debugger it says undefined, and the 'type of obj.dataValues' is object , not Array or Symbol, I use NodeJS 0.10.x